# Is it forbidden to chant Om?

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, hinduism

It is a common Hindu meditative practice to chant Om, which is the sound of the universe. Would doing so then transgress mitzvah 35 in Sefer Hamitzvot that prohibits chanting incantations which would heal a snake bite (https://www.chabad.org/dailystudy/seferhamitzvos.asp?tdate=6/29/2021). The Om is believed to have healing effects, possibly through relaxation and focus but this is likely not because of the words themselves conferring magical properties but the psychological effects of humming this sound.

Comment: You might find this interesting: [Kosher meditation](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3332306/jewish/Kosher-Meditation.htm) - he mentions there that many meditation practices incl. foreign gods. So watch out

Comment: Beyond this, answering this question might require detailed understanding of this Hindu practice, and possibly Hinduism as a religion, and would therefore be out of scope for MY